# Suppress "program not found" errors in Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Most of my team uses a .bat file to set paths and then run a build. The .bat file allows selection of multiple different compiler/target platforms, but all use some version of GCC/G++ or similar compiler.

I created an Eclipse project that simply uses the .bat file rather than re-inventing the wheel and tracking down all the paths needed for each build (which I'd need to update if anyone ever updated the .bat file anyway).

This works great for building, and I can even see compiler errors/warnings, but there are some extra errors always present:

```
Program "gcc" not found in PATH
Program "g++" not found in PATH
```

I've seen many questions about these and similar errors, but in those case the user couldn't build, and the solution was to install the tools and/or update their PATH or Eclipse environment settings. I don't want to do that; all the tools I need are installed, and the .bat file works just fine to set the PATH for building. Is there a way to suppress these errors, or have Eclipse not try to find the compiler executable, since the build succeeds anyway?

---

**Edit**: As suggested in the answer I've received so far, here is output on the console after putting a full path to a compiler in the global discovery settings, which isn't exactly my favorite solution even if it worked, but I'll probably deal with it. Regardless the errors don't go away:

```
15:27:24 **** Running scanner discovery: CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings MinGW ****
"C:\\redacted\\localapps\\MinGW5\\bin\\g++.exe" -E -P -v -dD C:/Project_Files/redacted/code_workspaces/redacted/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core/spec.C 
Reading specs from C:/redacted/localapps/MinGW5/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/specs
Configured with: ../gcc/configure --with-gcc --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --host=mingw32 --target=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw --enable-threads --disable-nls --enable-languages=c,c++,f77,ada,objc,java --disable-win32-registry --disable-shared --enable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-libgcj --disable-java-awt --without-x --enable-java-gc=boehm --disable-libgcj-debug --enable-interpreter --enable-hash-synchronization --enable-libstdcxx-debug
Thread model: win32
gcc version 3.4.2 (mingw-special)
 C:/redacted/localapps/MinGW5/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/cc1plus.exe -E -quiet -v -P -iprefix C:\redacted\localapps\MinGW5\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/ C:/Project_Files/redacted/code_workspaces/redacted/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core/spec.C -dD
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/redacted/localapps/MinGW5/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../mingw32/include"
#define __cplusplus 1
ignoring nonexistent directory "/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/../../../include/c++/3.4.2"
#define __STDC_HOSTED__ 1
ignoring nonexistent directory "/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/../../../include/c++/3.4.2/mingw32"
#define __GNUC__ 3
ignoring nonexistent directory "/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/../../../include/c++/3.4.2/backward"
...
```

And then a bunch of `#define`s

The command string I used in the discovery options for this output was `C:\redacted\localapps\MinGW5\bin\${COMMAND}.exe ${FLAGS} -E -P -v -dD "${INPUTS}"`.

Comment: Do you launch Eclipse CDT from the bat file, or is the bat file used to do the build? Also can you clarify where you are seeing the error? In the CDT Build console (per project or global), another console or somewhere else?

Comment: I use the .bat file in the build configuration in Eclipse, I do not launch Eclipse from the .bat file. These errors appear in the problems view in Eclipse, not the build console.

Comment: I have guessed at your problem based on the information provided. If my answer is not correct, please specify the full details from the Problem view and also the version of CDT/Eclipse you are using as it may be the quality of the error messages may be better in more recent versions.

Comment: As an aside, GCC 3.4.2 is positively ancient (almost 12 Years old!) and itself may be the cause of strange behaviour. What version of gdb are you using. I believe CDT are now officially only supporting gdb version 7.1 and above (but I have to look it up to be sure)

Comment: Good to know. It looks like version 6.6 is what is included in that "official" package I'm getting the compiler from, although I may be using a gdb from a different installer location. At least I know a plausible reason if gdb does strange things in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the information provided, these errors are coming from the scanner discovery part of CDT.

On my machine the full error looks like this:

```
Description                             Location                                                                                        Type
Program "g++" not found in PATH         Preferences, C++/Build/Settings/Discovery, [CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings MinGW] options   C/C++ Scanner Discovery Problem
Program "gcc" not found in PATH         Preferences, C++/Build/Settings/Discovery, [CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings MinGW] options   C/C++ Scanner Discovery Problem
```

Or as a screenshot

[image: problems view]

What is going on here is Eclipse CDT is (attempting to) launch GCC and G++ to find out what the *global* settings are for things like include paths, etc.

To fix the problem, go to the Location specified in the error message and adjust the scanner settings. Here is the matching setting to go with the specific error I received.

[image]

Your error might be in the project or in the global settings.

To update the MinGW setting, you can provide the path to a batch file that looks like GCC/G++ but sets up your environment correctly first, or you can point directly at the GCC that Eclipse CDT did not find on its own.

For example you can have:

```
D:\path\to\my\compilers\${COMMAND}.exe ${FLAGS} -E -P -v -dD "${INPUTS}"
```

As the setting instead of the default.

To aid the debugging, check the *Allocate console in the Console View* to see exactly what is being run and what output is being generated.

And here is what you might see when it does not work. Hopefully the error messages in the console are sufficient to resolve the problem on your machine.

```
21:12:54 **** Running scanner discovery: CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings MinGW ****
"D:\\path\\to\\my\\compilers\\g++.exe" -E -P -v -dD C:/Temp/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core/spec.C 
Cannot run program "D:\path\to\my\compilers\g++.exe": Launching failed

Error: Program "D:\path\to\my\compilers\g++.exe" not found in PATH
PATH=[\bin;\bin; -- snip --]

21:12:54 Build Finished (took 37ms)
```

Here is a screenshot to match:

[image]

If it does work, you should see lots of `#define`s and the like showing the global state of your compiler.

Comment: I think you're correct; at least, you've guessed at the full error message I'm receiving. But I cannot figure out how to fix the configuration. I tried giving a full path to the gcc.exe used by the default build in place of "${COMMAND}" in my global configuration for the MinGW compiler settings (shown in your second screen shot) but the errors remained. Note that I do not have a Discovery tab in the project settings, only in the global settings, although the label at the top of the settings page claims they can be overridden by project-specific settings somehow.

Comment: It should be a matter of entering your custom command instead of `${COMMAND}` . Try Allocating a console in the console view to see exactly what is being run. For example with the console and my custom batch file I see the output: `20:54:28 **** Running scanner discovery: CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings MinGW ****
"c:\\path\\to\\my.bat" -E -P -v -dD C:/Temp/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core/spec.C 
`

Comment: PS overriding won't solve your problem because once you tell CDT you are using MingGW I think it will try and get the global settings (even though it won't use them) so you will still have the error message.

Comment: When I specify a full path to a compiler instead of ${COMMAND}, the errors don't go away. I can't use my .bat file because the .bat file is a wrapper for make, not the compiler.

Comment: What output do you have in the console?

Comment: From that my guess is the error messages are stale, they should have been cleared. Please try deleting the errors from the problems view and restart. If they come back and refer to exactly the location you have fixed up then you must have hit a bug that I can try to minimise with your help and fix in CDT.

Comment: I experimented on my machine for every piece of advice I gave and never had a stale error message btw. Also as you can see from my last screenshots the error message in the problems view refers to the full path I entered when it was not working.

Comment: I deleted the errors and restarted Eclipse as you suggest. They do not come back, even after a full clean/build cycle, or rebuilding the index. So it looks like you're correct that the errors are stale. Thanks!